# Unity Everyplay Xcode Build error

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, everyplay

Unity 4.5.1 : http://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-4.5.1 
Everyplay - ### 1801-1100 - May 20th 2014 from https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/16005
Xcode - 5.1.1
Project Build settings: IOS Device SDK. Target OS version 5.0

Error:
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "UnitySetScreenOrientation(int)", referenced from:
      -[EveryplayUnity everyplayHidden] in EveryplayUnity.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Project was building fine before I upgraded to Unity 4.5.1 from Unity 4.5

Project is building fine if I disable the IOS enabled flag/bit in Everyplay Editor setting
Everyplay is working okay if I comment out the following two lines in EveryplayUnity.o
ScreenOrientation orientation = ConvertToUnityScreenOrientation(newOrientation, 0);
UnitySetScreenOrientation(orientation);

What's the best solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update (release 1801-1120) has been sent to Asset Store, it'll take a while to get there

Meanwhile, it's also available through Github, thanks!

https://github.com/Everyplay/everyplay-ios-sdk